# iPads and Dual 150 GPS Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gps

How does an external bluetooth gps like the dual 150 integrate with the CLLLocationManager?  Does it automatically integrate or is there a special API that is used to work with the external GPS rather than the internal GPS?

Comment: I asume that it does not integrate, you have to do all yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that it does "automatically" integrate with Location Services using the Dual App from the App Store.

1. Ensure that the device is in "Apple" mode (switch near power socket)
2. Ensure that device is paired with *YOUR* IOS device (IOS Bluetooth Settings)
3. Ensure that the Dual blue light is solid (Bluetooth Paired)
4. Ensure that the Dual green light is flashing (GPS Synching) or solid (GPS Synched)
   if off rerun the Dual App
5. If still not working, power cycle Dual, goto 1.
6. If still not working, power cycle IOS device, goto 1.

Comment: Do you need to do anything special in your app to read the values from the external unit? I wrote an app that gets location data using the iOS CoreLocation framework and it doesnt seem to use the XGPS unit. I tried their app from the app store and that does use it. I noticed that the paperplane near the battery shows itself when I use my app but disappears when I use theirs (I'm assuming because it pulls GPS from the unit using bluetooth and NOT the GPS chip on the phone)

Comment: If you do the above, it should work.  Did you get this working?